# Separate meshes by material

Tags: python, mesh

I am dealing with an obj import from a different program - which I have no control on.

The output is one single mesh, different logical parts of which are assigned different materials.

I would like to separate the mesh by material - so that from the state below:

[image]

I could get to one with two separate meshes, one per material.

How is that done - both manually and (ideally) with python/bpy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [`bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='MATERIAL')`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.separate)

> Separate selected geometry into a new mesh

You can use [`mesh.separate()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.separate) in *Edit Mode* and pass `'MATERIAL'` to its type argument:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# If object type is mesh and mode is set to object
if C.object.type == 'MESH' and C.mode == 'OBJECT':
    # Edit Mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    # Seperate by material
    bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='MATERIAL')
    # Object Mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```